# Use mutate to create rows instead of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Some data:

```
webdata %>% dput
structure(list(`2021-01-01` = c(9769.77145143346, 240.374021734625
), `2021-01-02` = c(9747.83506410782, 205.305063093191), `2021-01-03` = c(10244.2824708895, 
253.285005879351), `2021-01-04` = c(9903.98090317497, 250.068739190171
), `2021-01-05` = c(10126.8521068156, 152.172995948704), Total = c(sessions = 49792.7219964214, 
conversions = 1101.20582584604)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("sessions", 
"conversions"))
```

Looks like this:

```
webdata
            2021-01-01 2021-01-02 2021-01-03 2021-01-04 2021-01-05     Total
sessions      9769.771  9747.8351  10244.282  9903.9809  10126.852 49792.722
conversions    240.374   205.3051    253.285   250.0687    152.173  1101.206
```

I'd like to add a row, `ConversionRate` which is `conversions / sessions`. This is like a transposed `dplyr` operation since I need a row mutation.

How can I do this so that there's a new row for `ConversionRate` that is `conversions / sessions`?

Comment: If you use base R this works: `rbind(webdata, ConversionRate = webdata[1, ] / webdata[2, ])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**
In case you would like to use rownames instead of indices to carry out your operation, I think this solution may be helpful for your original data set:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ (.x)[which(rownames(df) == "sessions")]/
                     .x[which(rownames(df) == "conversions")]),
            rowname = 'ConversionRate') %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              rownames_to_column()) %>%
  column_to_rownames("rowname")

               2021-01-01 2021-01-02  2021-01-03 2021-01-04  2021-01-05       Total
ConversionRate   40.64404   47.47976    40.44567   39.60503    66.54829    45.21654
sessions       9769.77145 9747.83506 10244.28247 9903.98090 10126.85211 49792.72200
conversions     240.37402  205.30506   253.28501  250.06874   152.17300  1101.20583
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I like this answer. My real data has multiple rows, I kept this minimal to just 'sessions' and 'conversions'. Using your sytntax, it looks like you select the row based on ordering? (first(.x), last(.x). What's this doing? Can I adjust this to be based on the rowname rather than an index?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Yes since it involved multiple columns transformations, I thought this approach would be less verbose. It actually multiplies first value of each column by its last value, and if the order of rownames are correct it will lead to your desired result. But if you wanna use rownames instead of indices I possibly need to change the solution.

Comment: "But if you wanna use rownames instead of indices I possibly need to change the solution." if you wouldn't mind showing me how to do this I'd be very grateful

Comment: No it's totally fine. I just didn't understand what would you like me do. You would like to use rownames instead of indices right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I shouldn't have made my example so minimal. Pretend there are 4 or 5 rows and the ordering is not consistent, so I'd want to conversions / sessions based on the row name as opposed to the ordering of the rows

Comment: @DougFir check my update please. I hope this also works with your original data.

Comment: That's my pleasure, just let me know how it fares on your original data.

Answer (score 2):

May be this also do

```r
library(tidyverse)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

webdata %>%
  bind_rows(webdata %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~last(.)/first(.))) %>% `row.names<-`('Rate'))

#>               2021-01-01   2021-01-02   2021-01-03   2021-01-04   2021-01-05
#> sessions    9.769771e+03 9.747835e+03 1.024428e+04 9.903981e+03 1.012685e+04
#> conversions 2.403740e+02 2.053051e+02 2.532850e+02 2.500687e+02 1.521730e+02
#> Rate        2.460385e-02 2.106161e-02 2.472452e-02 2.524932e-02 1.502668e-02
#>                    Total
#> sessions    4.979272e+04
#> conversions 1.101206e+03
#> Rate        2.211580e-02
```

---

As mentioned in comments, if you want to use rownames

```
webdata %>%
  bind_rows(webdata %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~first(.x[rownames(webdata) == 'conversions'])/
                                           first(.x[rownames(webdata) == 'sessions']))) %>% `row.names<-`('Rate'))

              2021-01-01   2021-01-02   2021-01-03   2021-01-04   2021-01-05        Total
sessions    9.769771e+03 9.747835e+03 1.024428e+04 9.903981e+03 1.012685e+04 4.979272e+04
conversions 2.403740e+02 2.053051e+02 2.532850e+02 2.500687e+02 1.521730e+02 1.101206e+03
Rate        2.460385e-02 2.106161e-02 2.472452e-02 2.524932e-02 1.502668e-02 2.211580e-02
```

Though it is safer to use aggregating functions while summarising, still, the below code will also work

```
webdata %>%
  bind_rows(webdata %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~.x[rownames(webdata) == 'conversions']/
                                           .x[rownames(webdata) == 'sessions'])) %>% `row.names<-`('Rate'))
```

Comment: Hi, what are `first()` and `last()`? I'm reading ?across but don't see any reference to it? What are those functions doing here?

Comment: @DougFir, actually `first` and `last` are aggregating functions.  See revised answer in case you want to use rownames instead.  Still, it is safer to use any of the agregating function like max/min/sum/mean/first/last, which in this case will all give same results

Answer (score 2):

We may also do this in `summarise` itself`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
webdata %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
    summarise(rn = c(rn, 'Rate'), across(-rn, ~ c(., first(.)/last(.)))) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('rn')
```

-output

```
         2021-01-01 2021-01-02  2021-01-03 2021-01-04  2021-01-05       Total
sessions    9769.77145 9747.83506 10244.28247 9903.98090 10126.85211 49792.72200
conversions  240.37402  205.30506   253.28501  250.06874   152.17300  1101.20583
Rate          40.64404   47.47976    40.44567   39.60503    66.54829    45.21654
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
webdatanew <- rbind(webdata,sapply(webdata, function(x) x[1,drop = T]/x[2, drop = T]))
rownames(webdatanew)
[1] "sessions"    "conversions" "3"          
rownames(webdatanew)[3] <- 'ConversionRate'
webdatanew
               2021-01-01 2021-01-02  2021-01-03 2021-01-04  2021-01-05       Total
sessions       9769.77145 9747.83506 10244.28247 9903.98090 10126.85211 49792.72200
conversions     240.37402  205.30506   253.28501  250.06874   152.17300  1101.20583
ConversionRate   40.64404   47.47976    40.44567   39.60503    66.54829    45.21654
```